# eval "the serialized object using JavaScriptSerializer()" after removing special characters

Tags: jquery, json, eval, javascriptserializer

I need to eval an JavaScriptSerializer() object.

```
var userSettings = '<%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["UserSettings"]) %>';
```

The above line gives the output as:

```
{"SalesTaxPercentage":7.75,"StartOfWeek":"SUNDAY","NoofRowsInList":10,"ShowDashboardEntry":5,"DisplayContactsFormat":"LastName, FirstName","FooterNotes":""When you look good, you feel good...when you feel good, your attitude changes...and attitude is everything!"

You are the heart of my business....THANK YOU!"}
```

When i use eval for the serialized content like:

```
userSettings = eval("(" + userSettings + ")");
```

It throws an error:

> missing } after property list

This is because of the special characters in the serialized object (in FooterNotes with " and some other characters in between start and end quotes) during eval.

How can i remove the special characters in serialized before eval?

Or how can i get the value of `SalesTaxPercentage` from searialized object?

Comment: Did you find an answer? if so, please be socially responsible and post it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply remove single quotes in the first string and don't use eval (`userSettings` will be already an object).

Another way is to double backslashes so your string will stay quoted, something like this (not tested):

```
var userSettings = '<%= System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
    new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["UserSettings"]), @"\134", "\\$0"); %>';
```

Comment: The problem is i need to get the value of "SalesTaxPercentage", which i was not able to get without eval. If i use eval, i can get that value simply by accessing "userSettings.SalesTaxPercentage"

Comment: I meant you could write `var userSettings = <%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization... %>;` and then you could get that value by "userSettings.SalesTaxPercentage". No need to use eval in that case: "Since JSON is a subset of JavaScript, it can be used in the language with no muss or fuss."